# How to save multiple array usign Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

1. when you select dept and batch, and press next the program get you in a new page where the program show the student list by the selected dept and batch.
   [Have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/42PPy.png)
2. now from the student list page when you select some student's ID and  click next the program will get you in the subject selection page where you can assign some subject for them and when you click next button the program will save the subjects under the selected student.
   [Have a look here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eac76.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$this->db->insert_batch('table_name', $data);
```

where `$data` is a 2D array

[Official Doc](http://www.codeigniter.com/docs#insert)